# How to show logfile in spring-boot-admin?

Tags: java, spring, log4j2, spring-boot-admin

I'm using `spring-boot-admin-ui` to monitor my web applications.
Logging is configured with `log4j2`, in `log4j2-spring.xml`.

Question: how can I show those logfiles in admin-ui? As far as I read it could display `logback` out of the box. But how can I enable `log4j2` support, if possible at all?

The logfile is like:

```
<Loggers>
   <Root level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="APP" />
        <AppenderRef ref="XML" />
        <AppenderRef ... />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

I'd like to see the last X lines of the logfiles in admin-ui, or being able to directly download them via ui.

Answer (score 6):

you need to make sure the `/logfile`-endpoint from spring boot actguator is active. For example by setting the `logging.file` property. You can also configure a non-boot managed logfile by using `endpoints.logfile.external-file`.

Comment: OK, setting the `endpoints.logfile.external-file` to one the log4j created files worked. I though it would be auto-discovered, and one could see all logfiles created. But in fact currently it's only possible to set a hardlink to one of them.

Comment: `endpoints.logfile.external-file` is deprecated use `management.endpoint.logfile.external-file`

Answer (score 1):

It is enough just to add a property file to the `application.properties`

```
"logging.file.name=logging.txt".
```

P.S. The name of the file and its extension to test.

Answer (score 0):

Both options mentioned in other answers need:

1. 'logfile' actuator endpoint exposing

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
         include: logfile
  endpoint:
    logfile: 
      enabled: true
```

2. adding log file in section 'logging':

```
logging:
  file:
    name: logging.txt # ant name
```